# How to make bundle.css and bundle.js files

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, sass

I've been creating a basic website and have been working on the front end. And I preview it using the command `npm start`.

In my directory, I have these files

```
app.js
app.scss
index.html
package-lock.json
package.json
webpack.config.js
```

It's time for me to tie it in with my backend (Flask and Python programs), and I think I need to compile everything to get bundle.css and bundle.js files. However, I cannot seem to find the command to compile everything and generate these files. I assume they would be some npm command. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try these bundler libraries. Read the documentation and follow the required format.

1. Webpack: https://webpack.js.org/
2. ParcelJS: https://parceljs.org/

Comment: Yeah, webpack can minify and bundle js and css files

Comment: @PauloCosta Yeah you don't need both of them. Yes Webpack will do the honor. But at least try Parcel as well because it's easy to use.